# Does ssh server require or use tuntap interface when tunneling?

Tags: tun

I'm creating app to tunnel ipv4 packet using tuntap on client side and no tuntap on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to login as root to ssh server you can prepare tuntap devices on both sides (client and server)

```
MODE=tap
DEV=tap0
IP=9.0.0.1 # client and server must be different

sudo ip tuntap add ${DEV} mode ${MODE}
sudo ifconfig ${DEV} ${IP} up
```

and login as `ssh user@server -o Tunnel=ethernet -w 0:0` (no root needed).

If you want `tun` dont use `-o Tunnel=ethernet` in ssh command and set `MODE` to `tun` and `DEV` to `tun0`